# Ignore synchronization for $http, but not $timeout

Tags: javascript, angularjs, selenium, testing, protractor

Is there a way to ignore synching with the http request for a angular app?

I have this form that should be disabled during the POST of the form. When this POST request is pending, the form should be disabled and this is what I would like to write specs for.

So in Protractor I fill out the form and click on the send button. The request will never get a response, waiting until the browser ends the request due to a timeout (usually 30 secs), so I have time to check if the form is disabled. But since Protractor wants to sync with http requests, a pending request would render in a timeout from Protractor.

So I added the line `browser.ignoreSynchronization = true`, making Protractor ignore syncing http request. But I believe this also means ignoring syncing with angular as a whole, not waiting until angular have updated data-bindings for example before Protractor moves on.

Comment: Can you please describe your app logic and what do you test? It seems to me you are want part of Angular to work and another not to work. If you do so, then your tests will not test real app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, you have to tweak `ignoreSynchronization` - set it to `true`, check the form and set it back to `false` after.

There is something more convenient about it coming in the future, stay tuned:

- [Make it easier to control when `ignoreSynchronization` is off or on](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/1939)

Comment: But Protractor doesn't wait for angular then. And I want to wait for data-bindings to update. I just don't want to be stalled by http requests.

Comment: Using `browser.wait()` right now. Guess I have to stick with it then.

Comment: @Olov I am afraid you cannot have the one without the other. What you can/have to do is to use `browser.wait()` explicit waits to wait for specific conditions on a page.